# How do I set pandoc latex template options with knitr's pandoc() function using an embedded pandoc config?

Tags: knitr, pandoc

Is it possible to use knitr's pandoc() function with an embedded pandoc config in a markdown file to change the default pandoc latex template options?

For example, if I use the following embedded pandoc() config at the beginning of foo.md:

```
<!--pandoc
format: latex
s: 
V: geometry:margin=1.5cm
o: foobar.pdf
-->
```

Then, from R prompt,

```
pandoc("foo.md","latex")
```

produces the following system call from R:

```
pandoc -s -V=geometry:margin=1.5cm  -f markdown -t latex -o foobar.pdf 'foo.md'
```

However, For the page margins to actually be adjusted to 1.5cm, the system call needs to NOT have the "=" after the -V.  In other words, the system call needs to be:

```
pandoc -s -V geometry:margin=1.5cm  -f markdown -t latex -o foobar.pdf 'foo.md'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is a bug of knitr that has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) (1.2.7) on Github.

Comment: Yihui...THANKS.  Works just like you promised.